# Maximum value of fields of nested structure

Tags: matlab, struct, vectorization

I have following structure:

```
S.s1.val = 1;
S.s2.val= 5;
S.s3.val= 4;
...
S.s10.value = 3;
```

How can I find max value of all **val** fields without using loops. And what is general solution to apply functions to all nested structure fields?

Comment: It's actually a little simpler, have a look at my edit

Comment: I agree. Thank you!

Comment: Why not `S(1).val, S(2).val, ..., S(10).val`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *general solution*, but one way to think of is [**`structfun`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) to collect the data you want to process to an array.

```
maxval = max( structfun(@(x) x.val, S) )
```

Internally `structfun` works serially like a loop, so if you're really into speed, don't use structs (or cell arrays).

Comment: Thank you for the solution!